# Nodejs Express is repeating GET request

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-dynamodb

I have an issue with my application. I have a long request running on a DynamoDB. This scan takes a long time but keeps crashing.
Exactly every 2 minutes my server restarts the `GET request` before the initially started query is finished. This leaves my server with another started query every 2 minutes until the first query finishes and sends the callback.

This is the line of code that I am using for the scan.

```
if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(returnData.Items,data.Items);
    params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
    docClient.scan(params, onScan);              
}else{
    console.log("Scanning complete");
    if(returnData.Items){
        Array.prototype.push.apply(returnData.Items,data.Items);
        callback(null, returnData);
    }else{
        callback(null, data);
    }                    
}
```

Is there any way to block these repeating request?

```
[15/May/2018:14:26:25 +0000] "GET /scan?{parameters} HTTP/1.1"
```

Or am I required to do all of this as an AJAX Request after loading the page?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default timeout for a request in Node.js is 2 minutes.

If your request needs more time, you can set it after your server started:

```
server.timeout = 300000; // (5 minutes in msecs)
```

For more information, check the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_timeout).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I fell ill and was not able to do so for the last week. But it solved my problem perfectly.